# How to mock data with array inside object in jest

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am using jest for unit testing in react native. Here is my componentWillMount() function:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    axios.get(SERVER_URL + '/courses')
        .then(response => {

            this.state.trainingcatalogues = []
            this.state.traininglist = []
            this.state.Location1 = []
            this.state.Category1 = []
            this.state.Location2 = ['All']
            this.state.Category2 = ['All']                
            for (var key in response.data) {
                if (response.data[key].coursetype === 'Instructor-Led' && response.data[key].status === 'Active' ) {
                    this.state.Location1.push(response.data[key].location);
                    this.state.Category1.push(response.data[key].category);
                    this.state.trainingcatalogues.push(response.data[key]);
                    this.state.traininglist.push(response.data[key]);
                }
            }
```

I want to mock the 'response' in my test case. It has the following format:

```
let response = 
   {
     "data": [
       {
         "_id": "5acb16701e09ae8abc29e7fb",
         "courseName": "Agile Fundamentals420",
         "category": "Agile",
         "coursetype": "Instructor-Led",
         "duration": 22,
         "addnote": "contractor",
         "status": "Completed",
         "registrations": 10
       }
     ]
   }
```

This is my unit test case:

```
it('should test the componentwillMount function', () => {
 const wrapper = shallow(<Instructor_cata navigation = {navigation}/>);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    const componentWillMountSpy = jest.spyOn(instance,"componentWillMount");
    instance.forceUpdate();
    instance.componentWillMount();
    expect(componentWillMountSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

});

How do I mock this response data inside the unit test case?

Comment: You will need to mock the axios library

Comment: @dentemm Can you please tell how to proceed with that?

Comment: Added an answer below to help you get started

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You wil need to mock the Axios library, and there are several options to do so. First there are some libraries like axios-mock-adapter or jest-mock-axios, but you might as well just write a mock yourself, it is not much work.

Basic example:

```
// mock.js: custom axios mock file in your tests folder

module.exports = {
  get: jest.fn((url) => {

    switch (url): {
      case '<your_url>/courses':
        return Promise.resolve(<your_response_object>)

      default: 
        return Promise.resolve({...})
    })
  }
};
```

Just import the mock in your test files. And you can use a similar approach for other axios methods like post().